# meaning - top of the mountain or summit

Tags: meaning, word-choice, difference, nouns

In an everyday situation to address the very top of a mountain is better to say:

> at the top of the mountain

Or

> at the summit of the mountain

And again what's the difference between the two? In which situation you should use them?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78030/peak-vs-summit

Comment: Alternatively you could use _at the mountain's [peak](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peak)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both exactly the same. The summit is defined as the top of a mountain. I can't think of any situation where I would prefer one over the other.

Comment: so there is no difference whatsoever?

Comment: Nope, none whatsoever.

Comment: One caveat - "summit" can be used as a verb by climbers.  "I summited Kilimanjaro last year".  They would not say "I topped ..."

Comment: @JohnFeltz True. The noun summit and the verb summit have different meanings (as do the noun top and the verb top).